# Dynamic EntityManager find () method returns "table not found" when a custom repository is in use

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

First I will explain why and how the solution works and then the problems I have encountered. If you think there is a better way to do what I do, I'd love to hear it. I would also like to know why doctrine behaves in this way.

It turns out that my aplication needs to connect to a different database according to the client. I have a table, in a fixed database, containing the connection information that is used in some request.
I have had success with the following code:

```
class DynamicEntityManager {

protected $em;
private $request;

private $client_id;

public function __construct(RequestStack $request, EntityManagerInterface $em){
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function getEntityManager(ClientConn $client = null) {
    $request = $this->request->getCurrentRequest();  
    if($client == NULL){
        $domain = $request->attributes->get('domain');
        if($domain == "" || $domain == NULL){
            throw new \Exception("Error de conexion", 1);
        }
        $client = $this->em->getRepository(ClientConn::class)->findOneBy(array(
            "subdomain" => $domain
        ));
        if($client == NULL){
            throw new \Exception("Error de conexion", 1);                
        }
    }
    $connectionDB = $client->getConnection();
    $dbdriver = 'oci8';
    $conexionSplit = explode(':',$connectionDB);
    $dbhost = $conexionSplit[0];
    $dbport = $conexionSplit[1];
    $dbname = $conexionSplit[2];
    $dbuser = $client->getUsuarioBd();
    $dbpass = $client->getClaveBd();
    $service = false;

    $this->client_id = $client->getId();

    if(strpos($dbname,'SN=') !== false){
        $parts = explode('=',$dbname);
        $dbname = $parts[1];
        $service = true;
    }

    $request->attributes->set('client_id',$client->getId());

    $conn = array(
        'driver'    => $dbdriver,
        'host'      => $dbhost,
        'port'      => $dbport,
        'dbname'    => $dbname,
        'user'      => $dbuser,
        'password'  => $dbpass,
        'service'   => $service,
        'charset'   => 'UTF8',
        'schema'    => null
    );
    return EntityManager::create($conn, $this->em->getConfiguration());
    }
}
```

As you can see I return *EntityManager::create($conn, $this->em->getConfiguration ())* with the new connection. The way I use it is the next:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/api/client/{id}/conf/{confID}", name="conf.show")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function show(ClientConn $client, Request $request, DynamicEntityManager $dem ,$confId){
    try {

        $em = $dem->getEntityManager($client);
        $entity = $em->getRepository(Configuration::class)->find($confId);
        return new JsonResponse($entity, 200);
    }
    catch(\Exception $ex) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            "excepcion" => $ex->getMessage()
        ], $ex->getCode());
    }
}
```

It works as expected or so I believed until I saw that when the entity has a custom repository it is unable to use the dynamic connection and therefore the previous route will return a table not found exception.

> - @ORM\Entity() <-- Works like a charm
> - @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ConfigurationRepository")<-- Table not found.

It works in the repository if I create the connection again, although I do not like the solution. So, what do I want? I would like to be able to use the basic methods like find (), findBy () and others without having to rewrite them every time I use a custom repository.

```
class ConfigurationRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, DynamicEntityManager $dem)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, Configuration::class);
    $this->dem= $dem;
}

public function uglyFind($client, $confID)
{        
    $query = $this->dem->getEntityManager($client)->createQueryBuilder('conf')
    ->select("conf")
    ->from(ConfPedidosLentes::class,'conf')
    ->where('conf.id = :value')->setParameter('value', $confID)
    ->getQuery();

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

I will really appreciate any contribution and thought in this matter.

Comment: are there too many such connections?

Comment: about 80 and growing

Comment: If the problem is Table not found, did you try to add the `table` param for `@Entity()` 
(or `@Table()` I don't remember well) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
class ConfigurationRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, DynamicEntityManager $dem)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Configuration::class);
        $this->dem= $dem;
    }
    ...
```

try extending EntityRepository (without using a constructor) and use find as you did in your controller:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ConfigurationRepository extends EntityRepository
{

}
```

`ServiceEntityRepository` is  an optional `EntityRepository` base class with a simplified constructor for autowiring, that explicitly sets the entity manager to the `EntityRepository` base class. Since you have not configured your doctrine managers to handle these connections properly (it's not even possible actually with so many connections), `ServiceEntityRepository` will pass a wrong EntityManager instance to the `EntityRepository` subclass, that's why you should not extend `ServiceEntityRepository` but `EntityRepository`.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and tell you how it was.

Comment: `ServiceEntityRepository` extends `EntityRepository` so it shouldn't change anything. If it works, think about opening a bug report on doctrine2 bundle github.

Comment: It's not a bug. ServiceEntityRepository indeed extends EntityRepository but also explicitly passes an entity manager to the EntityRepository which in this case in not desired. I updated my answer to explain that.